# SQL 2005 Can I use keyword like in a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need a case statement that allows partial matches.  I get a syntax error, but am wondering if anything similar to this is possible.  If not, my secondary solution is to re-write as a cursor...
Example:

```
SELECT CASE ColumnName
           WHEN 'value1' THEN 'answer1'
           WHEN 'value2' THEN 'answer2'
           WHEN LIKE '%TEST%' THEN 'answer3'
       END AS Answer
FROM TableName
```

Comment: For the love of SQL, don't use a cursor!

Comment: You are using the "simple `CASE` expression" but you should be using the "searched CASE expression". See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN ColumnName = 'value1' THEN 'answer1'
           WHEN ColumnName = 'value2' THEN 'answer2'
           WHEN ColumnName LIKE '%TEST%' THEN 'answer3'
       END AS Answer
FROM TableName
```

example you can run

```
SELECT name,CASE 
           WHEN Name = 'sysobjects' THEN 'answer1'
           WHEN Name = 'syscols' THEN 'answer2'
           WHEN Name LIKE '%p%' THEN 'answer3'
           ELSE 'unknown'
       END AS Answer
FROM sysobjects
```

Answer (score 8):

Need to use a slightly different `CASE` syntax:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ColumnName LIKE 'value1' THEN 'answer1'
            WHEN ColumnName LIKE 'value2' THEN 'answer2'
            WHEN ColumnName LIKE '%TEST%' THEN 'answer3'
ELSE 'not like any of them' END [Answer]
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can nest CASE condition and CASE WHEN value clauses, like so:

```
SELECT CASE ColumnName
           WHEN 'value1' THEN 'answer1'
           WHEN 'value2' THEN 'answer2'
           ELSE CASE WHEN ColumnName LIKE '%TEST%' THEN 'answer3' END
       END AS Answer
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the "simple `CASE` expression" but you should be using the "searched `CASE` expression". See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

In sql ORACLE 10

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN instr(ColumnName, 'value1')>0 THEN 'answer1'
       WHEN instr(ColumnName,'value2')>0 THEN 'answer2'
       WHEN instr(ColumnName,'TEST')>0 THEN 'answer3'
       ELSE 'not like any of them' 
    END
FROM TableName
```