# SQL Replace an empty SQL SELECT with word

Tags: sql, case

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I would like to make a select, when the result is empty it should be replaced with 'empty'
Else the result should be there.
That is my try:

```
select case (count*) 
       when 0 then 'empty'
       ELSE
       THEVALUEOFTHECOLUM
END AS RESULT

from Database.table where CarID = 12;
```

Thanks for every comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687717/sql-2005-can-i-use-keyword-like-in-a-case-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but you might have to convert the second occurrence of `COUNT(*)` to VARCHAR depending on the database used:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0
    THEN 'empty'
    ELSE COUNT(*) -- CONVERT, TO_CHAR, ...
  END AS result
FROM Database.table where CarID = 12;
```

Comment: That will only return the count,  if you want the column you need replace the second count with MAX(collname), but that will only return one entry.

Comment: MAX is needed because Else want's to return one result.  You can use any aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN Q.countvalue = 0 THEN 'Empty' 
    ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), Q.countvalue) 
END AS RESULT
FROM 
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS countvalue
    FROM   Database.table WHERE CarID = 12
    ) AS Q
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels hacky to me, but it will return the column data.
It is not one query, but it's still setwise.

```
declare @tmp table (id int)
declare @cnt int
insert into @tmp select col from table
select @cnt = count(*) from @tmp
if(@cnt = 0)
begin
    select 'empty'
end
else
begin
    select * from @tmp
end
```

Comment: I want all colums, how can I make your code work? Is there a procedure needed?

Comment: @John I don't understand the question.  Where do you want all columns?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to code it with one query?
If there are no results -> no result found
else
  Show all results, not only one

```
declare @tmp table (id int) 
declare @cnt int 
insert into @tmp select col from table 
select @cnt = count(*) from @tmp 
if(@cnt = 0) 
begin     
select 'empty' 
end 
else 
begin     
select * from @tmp 
end
```