# SELECT CASE with LIKE statement sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to use SQL to query on some data I have in my access (2010) database.

What I would like to do is pull out all the people with IBS. (This I know how to do).
Then using SQL create a variable that stores 0 if there is "?IBS" (not diagnosed) or stores 1 if there is "IBS" stored (diagnosed IBS) within this variable.
This information is stored in a text variable called "AdditionalHealthProblems".

I'm trying to use a SELECT CASE statement with Like but cannot seem to get it to work.

```
SELECT AdditionalHealthProblems, 'Diagnosed' = 
       CASE 
           WHEN AdditionalHealthProblems LIKE '*?IBS*' THEN '0'
           ELSE '1'
       END
FROM tblFollowUpQs
WHERE (((tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems) Like '*IBS*'));
```

But this is not working. I'm getting an error in the "`'Diagnosed' = CASE WHEN AdditionalHealthProblems LIKE '*?IBS*' THEN '0' ELSE '1'END"` statement via an error message.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?
Or if there is a better way to get this information?

Thank you!

*-----------------EDIT--------------------*

Changed to

```
SELECT tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems, CASE 
WHEN tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems LIKE 'IBS' THEN '0' END As Diagnosed
FROM tblFollowUpQs
WHERE (((tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems) Like 'IBS'));
```

But its still not working...

The error message give a syntax error and highlights WHEN

---------------ANSWER--------------------------

Switched the select case to Switch() function and it worked!

Here's the final code:

```
SELECT tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems, Switch( tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems LIKE '*[?]*', 1, tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems NOT LIKE '*[?]*', 0)
FROM tblFollowUpQs
WHERE (((tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems) Like '*IBS*'));
```

Comment: Its a missing operator error message within that statement

Comment: check this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687717/sql-2005-can-i-use-keyword-like-in-a-case-statement

FYI: The wildcard is the '%' character.

Comment: like '%IBS%'   or   '%IBS_'    like does not use * or *? for substitutions or "regex"

Comment: changed it to this but its still not working. still getting the error message

'code' SELECT tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems, CASE WHEN tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems LIKE 'IBS' THEN '0' END As Diagnosed
FROM tblFollowUpQs
WHERE (((tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems) Like 'IBS'));
'code'

Comment: @newBee While your statement is true for _SQL Server_, it's not for Microsoft Access, which the post is tagged as. The same is true for macmacs statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Access does not support the `CASE...WHEN` statement. Use the `IIF` statement instead:

> IIF(*expression*, *value if true*, *value if false*)
>
> [reference](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx)

```
SELECT tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems, 
IIf(tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems Like "IBS",1,0) AS [Diagnosed] 
FROM tblFollowUpQs
WHERE (((tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems) Like "'IBS"));
```

If you need to use wildcard characters you can read more on [office.microsoft.com](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/examples-of-wildcard-characters-HA102809757.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I just figured that out as you answered!

Comment: Switch would work too, although personally I think the IIF is more readable.

Comment: I agree that IIf() would be the more common choice in this case, but [Switch()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) is nice for avoiding multiple nested IIf()s.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT AdditionalHealthProblems, Diagnosed= (
   CASE 
       WHEN AdditionalHealthProblems LIKE '?IBS' THEN '0'
       ELSE '1'
   END)
FROM tblFollowUpQs
WHERE (((tblFollowUpQs.AdditionalHealthProblems) Like '%IBS'));
```

Comment: Please explain the query.